# Find exact match with words in php?

Tags: php, regex, match, cakephp-2.1

I want to replace some words from available string with a anchor tag. But it creates problem for me. I am doing like below:

```
$post['Post']['comment'] = 'a class href';
$post['Post']['person'] = 'a';
$post['Post']['place'] = 'class';
$post['Post']['thing'] = 'href';

$thing = "<a class='searchName' href='javascript:void(0)'>".ucfirst($post['Post']['thing'])."</a>";
$person = "<a class='searchName' href='javascript:void(0)'>".ucfirst($post['Post']['person'])."</a>";
$place = "<a class='searchName' href='javascript:void(0)'>".ucfirst($post['Post']['place'])."</a>";

$search_strings = array($person=>$post['Post']['person'],$place=>$post['Post']['place'],$thing=>$post['Post']['thing']);
$kw_to_search_for = $post['Post']['comment'];
foreach($search_strings as $key=>$v)
{               
    if (preg_match('~\b' . $v . '\b~i', $kw_to_search_for, $m))
    {               
        $as[] = str_ireplace($v, $key, $kw_to_search_for);
    } 
}
```

Output of above code is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => **A** cl**A**ss href
    [1] => a **Class** href
    [2] => a class **Href**
)
```

But i don't want output like above. As per my requirement the output should be like below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => **A** class href
    [1] => a **Class** href
    [2] => a class **Href**
)
```

Kindly suggest asap.......

Comment: Why not use an xml parser?

Comment: This code example is missing a definition for the value of $post

Answer (score 0):

If you search using the spaces in your comment to delimit the words it will work.

```
foreach ($search_strings as $key=>$v)
{
    //space at the beginning?
    $a = preg_replace('/\s' . $v . '/i', " $key ", $kw_to_search_for);

    //space at the end?
    $b = preg_replace('/' . $v . '\s/i', " $key ", $kw_to_search_for);

    //if anything replaced, use it
    if ($a !== $kw_to_search_for)
    {
        $as[] = $a;
    }
    elseif ($b !== $kw_to_search_for)
    {
        $as[] = $b;
    }
}
```

The output has some of the extra spaces, but HTML should ignore that fine...

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  <a class='searchName' href='javascript:void(0)'>A</a> class href
    [1] => a <a class='searchName' href='javascript:void(0)'>Class</a>  href
    [2] => a class <a class='searchName' href='javascript:void(0)'>Href</a>
)
```